# How to set style ListBox items in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles

My XAML code is: `<ListBox Name="Seq"><TextBlock Name="txt1" Text="Hello"/></ListBox>`

Code-behind would be:`Seq.Style = ...;` or `txt1.Style=...;`

I want to make some items green, bold and italic. What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add style in App.xaml as per your requirement, for example :

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="mystyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
</Style>
```

and then you can apply that style to text block of list box as below:

```
this.txt1.Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("mystyle");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really should do is to bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` to an `IEnumerable<T>` and then add properties to the type `T` that you can bind to in an `ItemTemplate`, e.g.:

```
<ListBox Name="Seq">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt1" Text="{Binding TextProperty}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeOtherProperty}" Value="SomeValue">
                    <Setter TargetName="txt1" Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

As a quick fix you could define a `TextBlock` style in your XAML markup:

```
<ListBox Name="Seq">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="style" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <TextBlock Name="txt1" Text="Hello"/>
</ListBox>
```

...and set the `Style` property of the `TextBlock`, either programmatically:

```
txt1.Style = Seq.Resources["style"] as Style;
```

...or directly in the XAML markup:

```
<TextBlock Name="txt1" Text="Hello" Style="{StaticResource style}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. But it's somewhat long and obscure for a beginner like me!

Comment: Just add the Style to <ListBox.Resources> and use the one-liner in the code-behind...?